# Is it possible that make_shared has no any exception but returns a nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, make-shared

I am recently dealing with a problem with shared_ptr. I am curious if make_shared failed, it will raise exceptions right? Is there any kind of situation that the make_shared returned a nullptr but without any exceptions?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared <-- no. The thing throws an exception, er returns a valid shared pointer.

Comment: Assuming a conformant Implementation, no. If you're really paranoid, add a cassert `assert` that will get optimized out in release builds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared):

> `std::make_shared`
>   ...
>
> May throw std::bad_alloc or any exception thrown by the constructor of
>   T.

So, if you throw exception from your class' constructor, then `std::make_shared` will throw it too. Besides exceptions thrown from constructor, `std::make_shared` could throw `std::bad_alloc` exception on its own.

Therefore, you don't need to check if the result of `std::make_shared` is `nullptr`. Just be sure to catch the exception and properly handle it.